# delete row conditional on value in other rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset looking similar to this one

```
df1<-data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
           YEAR = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002),
           VALUE = c(1,2,3,3,3,2,5,6,2,3,4,4,2,1,2,1))

   ID YEAR VALUE
1   1 1999     1
2   1 2000     2
3   1 2001     3
4   1 2002     4
5   2 1999     3
6   2 2000     2
7   2 2001     5
8   2 2002     6
9   3 1999     2
10  3 2000     3
11  3 2001     4
12  3 2002     4
13  4 1999     2
14  4 2000     1
15  4 2001     2
16  4 2002     1
```

What I'd like is that if Value is lower than 3 the first time, the values in the rows from previous years with the same ID should be set to NA and be left unchanged otherwise. However, if there is a value greater or equal to 3 before there is a value of 2 or lower, the other entries for the same ID should not be changed, as you can see for ID number 2.

The outpout should look something like this:

```
df2<-data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
           YEAR = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002),
           VALUE = c(0,0,3,3,3,2,5,6,0,3,4,4,0,0,0,0))

   ID YEAR VALUE
1   1 1999     0
2   1 2000     0
3   1 2001     3
4   1 2002     4
5   2 1999     3
6   2 2000     2
7   2 2001     5
8   2 2002     6
9   3 1999     0
10  3 2000     3
11  3 2001     4
12  3 2002     4 
13  4 1999     0
14  4 2000     0
15  4 2001     0
16  4 2002     0
```

A `data.table` solution would be fine too.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate.

Comment: can you provide me with a link to the question that already has been asked? i have not been able to find it until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `data.frame`, can be extended to `data.table`:

```
for (i in unique(df1$ID))
{
    mask <- (df1[i == df1$ID,'VALUE'] > 2)
    mask <- cumsum(mask) == 0
    df1[i == df1$ID,'VALUE'][mask] <- 0 
}
```

or this more functional approach:

```
transform(df1, VALUE = ave(VALUE, ID, FUN = function(x)
  ifelse(cumsum(x > 2) == 0, 0, x)
))
```

Comment: thank you for your responses! both approaches work fine for the datasample that I provided but I must see, that I may have underestimated the difficulty of this task.

I actually need not only to have values deleted that are less than 2 but also are greater than 3 and I also have NA in the dataset that would need to be treated as values that are less than 2 and greater than 3.

Comment: i replaced the NA entries by 0 so this problem seems to be solved, however the other one remains